# Sequential cocos2d actions on different nodes

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite, ccaction

I need to run sequential cocos2d actions on different nodes. I know about `CCSequence` but that is not good for me since it allows running sequence of actions on the same node. How would I go about running sequential actions for this scenario:

- Move parent;
- Move two child nodes simultaneously;
- Move parent again;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a [CCCallFunc](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/0.9.0-alpha/interface_c_c_call_func.html) to your sequence then in the function that it calls, start a new sequence on a different node.

Rinse and repeat for each separate node you want to move.